# Why is search in Activity Monitor disabled?

Tags: activity-monitor

The search on my activity monitor app is disabled/grayed out. I can't figure out how to enable it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*ps: mac noob here, be gentle please! :)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The search doesn't function when Activity Monitor's view is set to "All Processes, Hierarchically". Open the view menu and change it to anything else, and it'll activate again.

Comment: Almost correct: it also doesn't work when you have "Applications in the last 8 hours" selected...

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me in Mojave.

Comment: It does work on Mojave, actually.