# Search shortcut and menu options not working in Activity Monitor

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, activity-monitor

**Note**: [Why is search in Activity Monitor disabled?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192213/why-is-search-in-activity-monitor-disabled) is a similar but different issue that doesn't address the one here (I tried switching views to and from *Hierarchically*.

The <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut doesn't seem to work in Activity Monitor. Also, the **Find** menu options are greyed-out:

**Note:** <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>option ⌥</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> sets focus into the search bar

[image]

Although a search can still be preformed manually by clicking into the search box, the **Find** menu items remain disabled, except for *Jump to Selection*, which still doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Focus the Search bar via:

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Option ⌥</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>

However the **Find** menu items remain disabled, and their shortcuts don't work even with the option key.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You should [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/428078/edit) additional information into your original question body

Comment: @Tetsujin It provides a working shortcut to the search box, which is primarily what I was after. I figured to also post my observation about the search menu items being greyed-out

Answer (score 0):

It's not meant to work in the regular Processes window, it works in text files, such as that generated by Sample Process…

[image]

Comment: It acts as a filter in the Processes window

Comment: What does? You're invoking cmd/opt/F to access the search bar - that's a pretty standard, almost global feature, used everywhere cmd/F has a different function.

Comment: The search box in the title bar of Activity Monitor filters by process name... Yeah, I'm beginning to realize that about cmd-F / cmd-opt-F